# problem with rubygems in windows

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems

I built Ruby 1.9 from scratch in Windows using MinGW, now I am trying to set up the environment and am having great difficulties getting the 'gem' command to work.

First not even 'irb' would work, so i added a bunch of paths to the `RUBYLIB` environment variable and now that works ok. But whenever i run 'gem' i get this error:
http://gist.github.com/291135

Anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

NOTE: i have to use MinGW and compile from scratch as I am intending to build c extensions in windows.

thanks

Comment: +1:  latest major version of Ruby on Windows.  Sounds brave to me.  Good luck, and hopefully your question is seen by somebody with the right mojo to take this one on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the exact output of the errors you're getting is not simple to determine the root of the failure.

But to help you out, I would recommend you install RubyInstaller package for 1.9 and also install the Development Kit on top of it.

You can get more instructions about this in the website [here](http://rubyinstaller.org), and the [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just built an extension using it and it worked perfectly, thanks!